# Spring Data MongoDB: Group Aggregation using $ifNull in _id

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb

I need to translate following MongoDb group aggregation to Java code:

```
{
        $group: {
            _id: {"startDate": {$ifNull: ["$startDate", null]}, "name": {$ifNull: ["$name", null]}},
            "items": {
                $push: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
}
```

But `Aggregation.group()` doesn't seem to provide functionality for `$ifNull` expressions. It only accepts Strings and Fields.

I know, it is possible to implement custom `AggregationOperation` and use `DBObject` to achieve this, but this approach is more of a workaround than a solution. It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36468292/10137373), but that answer was written in 2016.

Is there any other (new) way to handle this in Spring Data MongoDB?